# Derivation of linear discriminant analysis (LDA) decision boundary

Tags: classification, bayesian, normal-distribution, discriminant-analysis

I've been reading the Introduction to Statistical Learning and Elements of Statistical Learning by the Stanford professors Hastie and Robert Tibshirani and I've been trying to derive the discriminating function knowing the posterior for LDA, assuming common covariance matrix, p=1 and Gaussian distribution. [image: posterior LDA]. If our assumption for normal Gaussian distribution of the likelihood holds we obtain the Bayes Classifier.

In the second picture it's mentioned that we take the log of the posterior but detailed steps of the derivation are not provided and I'm not sure 
how to derive it.

[image: discriminating function of the LDA for p=1]

Answer (score 4):

I don't have sufficient reputation to comment or flag this question as a duplicate, but you can find the answer here!

[Linear Discriminant Analysis for $p=1$](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/146333/linear-discriminant-analysis-for-p-1?rq=1)

Comment: You need to wait to comment. Don't use the answers in this way.

Comment: Was hoping someone with higher reputation would see my answer and make the flag or comment themselves :) Was trying to help the OP get an answer somehow!